# Azure - GCP - connection via Openvpn

Tags: azure, openvpn, azure-vpn, vnet

I need to create connection between GCP and Azure cloud. There in Open vpn connection created between GCP and Azure cloud, OpenVPN azure IP is `10.5.1.5`.

In Azure I have core vnetA and satelite vnetB. Between vnetA and vnetB I have peering configured, **gateway transit** is enabled on both sides of peered vnets.

I have two route tables: RTableA, RTableB.

RTableA is associated with subnetA in vnetA,
RTableB is associated with subnetB in vnetB.

In RTableA I have routes

- 1.(Name GCPtraffic;addr.prefix `192.168.0.0/24`;virtual appliance/openvpn IP `10.5.1.5`),
- 2.(Name InternetGateway;addr.prefix `0.0.0.0/0`; Internet),
- 3.(Name Local; addr.prefix `10.5.1.0/24`; Virtual Network).

In RTableB I have only one route 1.(Name GCPtraffic;addr.prefix `192.168.0.0/24`;virtual appliance/openvpn IP `10.5.1.5`).

I have VMs: VmA located in subnetA, VmB located in subnetB.

I have connection both directions `VmA --> VmB`, `VmB --> VmA`, and I can connect `VmA --> GCP` network.

Problem is that I am not able to connect `VmB --> GCP` network. Is there any route missing in that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using a pure OpenVPN software for the VPN connection but the vNetB don't use a remote gateway.

If you could use Azure virtual network gateway, in hub-and-spoke network architecture, **gateway transit** allows spoke virtual networks(vNetB) to share the VPN gateway in the hub networks(vNetA). If the peering is already created, navigate to the peering resource, then enable the `Use remote gateways` option for peered vNetB. Read [Configure VPN gateway transit for virtual network peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-peering-gateway-transit) for more details.

For more information, you could create a Site to Site VPN Connection Between GCP and Azure with Google Private Access from [this blog](https://cloudywithachanceofbigdata.com/creating-a-site-to-site-vpn-connection-between-gcp-and-azure-with-google-private-access/).

Comment: Hi, unfortunately your solution does not work. In my environment when I check checkbox `allow gateway transit` in my HUB network, then when I am trying to check checkbos in my SPOKE netywork, option `Use remote gateways` is grayed out. I dont have vnet gateways in my environment.

Comment: You could expect more replies from other members, I am not familiar with  GCP and your OpenVPN settings. Also, it's recommended to post the network deployment issue on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Sure, its not about GCP cloud, I am just wondering what is missing in the azure cloud. If we nee something else to establish communication I mentioned. I didnt find any info on the MS websites.

Comment: I have doubted that gateway transit is enabled on both sides of the peered vnets. Compare with the Azure hub-spoke network, Could you check if there is a route to VNetB from your GCP network?